# Проблема с синтаксисом кода

Tags: c#

Не знаю в чём проблема кода. Пишет ошибку:

> CS1513

но не вижу где не хватает }

```
public OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.Comparetag == ("Obstacle"))
    {
        string FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();.GameOver;

    }
    else if (other.gameObject.Comparetag == ("Scoring"))
    {
        string FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();.IncreaseScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1513

Comment: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ

Comment: @aepot та за шо?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, как минимум, в лишних знаках `;`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кроме того, что должно означать

```
string FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().GameOver;
```

???

Если вы хотели объявить переменную и приравнять ей значение выражения справа, то вы забыли дать название переменной и написать знак равно.